# THREE.JS: How can I check that Group of objects was rendered?

Tags: canvas, three.js, screenshot, render

I need make the screenshot after group of my objects was added and rendered on scene;

I tried add eventListener to "added" event, which triggered when object was added to scene, but it still not rendered and as result it doesn't exist on screenshot;

```
    add: function ( object ) {

        if ( arguments.length > 1 ) {

            for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i ++ ) {

                this.add( arguments[ i ] );

            }

            return this;

        }

        if ( object === this ) {

            console.error( "THREE.Object3D.add: object can't be added as a child of itself.", object );
            return this;

        }

        if ( (object && object.isObject3D) ) {

            if ( object.parent !== null ) {

                object.parent.remove( object );

            }

            object.parent = this;
            object.dispatchEvent( { type: 'added' } );
```

> object.dispatchEvent( { type: 'added' } );

```
            this.children.push( object );

        } else {

            console.error( "THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.", object );

        }

        return this;

    },
```

As I understand it doesn't help me, because render is called after adding objects to scene and creating screenshot, that's why this subscribe does not help me;

Here example of code:

```
   let group = new THREE.Group();   

    // here some objects were added to group

    scene.add(group);

    window.open(renderer.domElement.toDataURL('image/png'), 'screenshot');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: **1)** Welcome to StackOverflow! There are many reasons why your objects might not be rendering. We'll need some more information in order to help you. Please consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (preferably a snippet) to help us debug what's going on. **2)** THREE.js does not emit a "rendered" event.

Comment: @TheJim01
 
Hi. thank you for advice. But my objects are rendered. All works correctly, but objects are rendered after moment when screenshot was created; It's my problem, I need find moment when they were rendered;

Comment: I assume you have a `requestAnimationFrame` loop running somewhere. Make sure you actually call `renderer.render(scene, camera);` before creating the screenshot. Either manually call it before your call to `window.open`, or include logic in your `requestAnimationFrame` loop to create the screenshot at the end of the call after the group is added.

Comment: @TheJim01
Oh, thank you!!! It works..))) it's too simple decision for me.